# PHP CURL request with PEM certificate unstable results

Tags: php, curl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to get results from a server which is protected with an PEM cerficate and private key.
I have results, but it is unstable. Most of te time i have response, sometimes an Curl error: NSS: private key from file not found.

The code:

```
    $url = escape($this->url).'/jira/rest/api/2/project';

    // Variables
    $apiGrantType = 'client_credentials';
    $cliendId = $this->username;                                     // Client ID
    $clientSecret = $this->password;                                 // Client Secret
    $certUserPwd = $cliendId . ":" . $clientSecret;             // Client ID:Client Secret
    $certFile = PATH_FILES.'certificate/cert.pem';                      // Private Cert
    $certKey = PATH_FILES.'certificate/key.pem';                      // Private Cert
    $certPassword = '*****';                            // Cert Password


    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, PWSTR);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $certFile);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $certKey);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, $certKey);

    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

    if(!$exec = curl_exec($curl))
    {
          echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    }

    dump($exec);
```

Sometimes it runs perfectly and returns the requested response.
Othertimes it return Curl error: NSS: private key from file not found.

Server where request is calling from is running on CENTOS 7 and PHP 7.2.

How can i make my request stable?

Comment: Hi Jurrien, maybe you are calling this file form different places and the `PATH_FILES` is not absolute? just a thought... because is strange that sometimes works and other times not.

Comment: Hi Ignacio, thanks for your reaction! PATH_FILES is always the same path, but i have replaced PATH_FILES with the absolute path to try and it's still showing the same behaviour.

Comment: Is the cert and key on a remote filesystem like NFS or something? Strange error to get intermittently. Have you tried with a PHP build linked against the latest version of curl and NSS? Or tried with a curl version linked against OpenSSL instead of NSS? I don't fully understand what's going on in the code, but curl is returning that error because this NSS library call is failing: https://dxr.mozilla.org/security/source/mozilla/security/nss/lib/pk11wrap/pk11cert.c#1098-1153

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but recently had same issue.

Based on the above code, it looks like the curl definitions are within a class, and that one is used with `include/include_once` or `require/require_once`.

In my case seems that using `include_once/require_once` was the reason, hence
you can replace any `include_once/require_once` in favour of `include/require`.

alternatively use something like

```
if (!class_exists('some_class')) {
    include 'some_path/some_class.php';
}
```